# How can I make Weld to distinguish [@Default@Any@Named] from [@Default@Any]?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I'm using `weld-se` for testing one of my `JSR-330` annotated class.

```java
@Inject HelloWorld any;
@Inject @Named("impl") HelloWorld namedAsImpl;
@Inject @Named("demo") HelloWorld namedAsDemo;
@Inject @Impl HelloWorld qualifiedWithImpl;
@Inject @Demo HelloWorld qualifiedWithDemo;
```

I successfully injected those fields with Guice, Dagger, and Dagger2.

I prepared a provider class.

```java
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorldWeldProvider {

    @Produces HelloWorld any() {
        return current().nextBoolean()
               ? new HelloWorldImpl() : new HelloWorldDemo();
    }

    @Produces @Named("impl") HelloWorld namedAsImpl() {
        return new HelloWorldImpl();
    }

    @Produces @Named("demo") HelloWorld namedAsDemo() {
        return new HelloWorldDemo();
    }

    @Produces @Impl HelloWorld qualifiedWithImpl() {
        return new HelloWorldImpl();
    }

    @Produces @Demo HelloWorld qualifiedWithDemo() {
        return new HelloWorldDemo();
    }
}
```

And Weld complains

```
WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type HelloWorld with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject ....any
  at ....any(HelloWorldDependencyInjectionTest.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Producer Method [HelloWorld] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Named ....namedAsDemo()],
  - Producer Method [HelloWorld] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Named ....namedAsImpl()],
  - Producer Method [HelloWorld] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces ....any()]
```

Is this normal? or is `CDI` works differently than `DI`?`

Comment: If I had to guess, you're violating [multiple qualifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#multiple_qualifiers) in the CDI spec.  CDI does leverage a best match approach for satisfying injection points, rather than exact match you might find in other frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Bean resolution for injection points is governed by the Highlander Principle: "There can be only one."

From the [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#builtin_qualifiers):

> If a bean does not explicitly declare a qualifier other than `@Named`,
>   the bean has exactly one additional qualifier, of type `@Default`. This
>   is called the default qualifier.

[and](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#injection_point_default_qualifier)

> If an injection point declares no qualifier, the injection point has exactly one qualifier, the default qualifier @Default.

So your unqualified injection point is indeed matched by three beans.

Your second question *Is CDI different from DI?* depends on your definition of DI. If you mean DI = [JSR330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330), then the answer is yes, or else there would be no point in creating a new spec.